# Servlet mapping not working correctly

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, path

After trying many different url paths I still am not able to map my jsp get request to my servlet. The request keeps returning a 404 resource not found. The jsp and servlet are located in the same /NOSESSION folder. Here is the call from the jsp

```
<form action="/webapps/xxxx-xxx-BBLEARN/NOSESSION/createLinkReturn_proc" method="get" name="the_form" onsubmit="validateForm();">
```

And my servlet looks like this

```
    package com.xxxx;        

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.Map.Entry;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;    
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

    @WebServlet("/NOSESSION/createLinkReturn_proc")
    public class createLinkReturn_proc extends HttpServlet {    
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {                
            LoggingManager.appendToLogFile("Made it into the servlet");
```

}

I am using Servlet 3.0 with an updated web.xml config. I shouldn't have to put the servlet mappings in the web.xml file, but I have tried that and it still didn't work that way. I have tried lots of combinations of mappings from simple "/createLinkReturn_proc" to "${pageContext.request.servletPath}/createLinkReturn_proc" and nothing has worked so far.

Comment: is `xxxx-xxx-BBLEARN` the servlet context of your application?

Comment: Are you sure /webapps/xxxx-xxx-BBLEARN/ is the proper context root?

Comment: `${pageContext.request.contextPath}${pageContext.request.servletPath}` ?  I think you should remove the "/webapps" part, as this is not part of the deployed contextPath even though it maybe a directory on the system.  I expect contextPath="/xxxx-xxx-BBLEARN" and servletPath="/NOSESSION/createLinkReturn_proc".  Manually breakpoint your doGet() method and run container in debug mode under an IDE.  Then use a browser to manually find the URL that hits the breakpoint like http://127.0.0.1:8080/xxxx-xxx-BBLEARN/NOSESSION/createLinkReturn_proc